# Login with Microsoft AD with perticular tenant using javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Anyone implemented login with Microsoft Azure AD with the particular tenant if a user is attached with multiple tenants

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share what you've looked for, what you've tried, and the specific issue you've come across. A good place to start would be to include the code showing how you are sending the user to sign in.

Comment: Are you trying to log in to an app registered in a tenant? Or you want to log in the tenant itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the particular tenant in the authorize `/endpoint` and `/token` endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Don't use `common` or `organizations`. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Allen Wu.I used directory id in place of common. And its worked